# Next day Central Pivot Range

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I've this code for present day CPR. Could anyone please help me to add CPR level for the next day.

```
indicator(title='Pivot Range', shorttitle='CD_PivotR', overlay=true)

sd = input(true, title='Show Daily Pivots?')

//Pivot Range Calculations - Mark Fisher
pivot = (high + low + close) / 3.0
bc = (high + low) / 2.0
tc = pivot - bc + pivot

//Daily Pivot Range 
dtime_pivot = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', pivot[1])
dtime_bc = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', bc[1])
dtime_tc = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', tc[1])

offs_daily = 0
plot(sd and dtime_pivot ? dtime_pivot : na, title='Daily Pivot', style=plot.style_circles, color=color.new(color.fuchsia, 0), linewidth=3)
plot(sd and dtime_bc ? dtime_bc : na, title='Daily BC', style=plot.style_circles, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), linewidth=3)
plot(sd and dtime_tc ? dtime_tc : na, title='Daily TC', style=plot.style_circles, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), linewidth=3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some trial and error, I got it right.

```
indicator(title='Pivot Range', shorttitle='CD_PivotR', overlay=true)
sd = input(true, title='Show Daily Pivots?')

//Pivot Range Calculations - Mark Fisher
pivot = (high + low + close) / 3.0
bc = (high + low) / 2.0
tc = pivot - bc + pivot

//Daily Pivot Range 
dtime_pivot = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', pivot[barstate.isconfirmed ? 0 : 1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
dtime_bc = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', bc[barstate.isconfirmed ? 0 : 1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
dtime_tc = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', tc[barstate.isconfirmed ? 0 : 1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)

offs_daily = 0
plot(dtime_pivot ? dtime_pivot : na, title='Daily Pivot', style=plot.style_circles, color=color.new(color.fuchsia, 0), linewidth=3)
plot(dtime_bc ? dtime_bc : na, title='Daily BC', style=plot.style_circles, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), linewidth=3)
plot(dtime_tc ? dtime_tc : na, title='Daily TC', style=plot.style_circles, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), linewidth=3)

st = input(true, title='Show tomorrow Pivots?')

D1 = dtime_pivot
D2 = dtime_bc
D3 = dtime_tc




if(barstate.islast)
    line.new(bar_index, D1, bar_index+1, D1, extend = extend.right, color=color.fuchsia)
    line.new(bar_index, D2, bar_index+1, D2, extend = extend.right, color=color.fuchsia)
    line.new(bar_index, D3, bar_index+1, D3, extend = extend.right, color=color.fuchsia)
```